# pip: error: No command by the name pip uninstall

Tags: python, pip

So, this is strange. I've been trying to setup a python dev environment on emacs - and I've attempted to setup ropemacs, rope and pymacs. It's just not biting however, complaining that the pymacs helper didn't start in 30 seconds. Well, I've decided to give up on this part of the setup (autocomplete is pretty good as it is) and I want to remove these "dead" packages. However, when I try to invoke **pip uninstall** I get the error message described in the title. Anyone else had this issue, or know how to get round it?

EDIT: pip version info

pip 0.3.1 from /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages (python 2.6)

Comment: Sounds like you're using an old version of `pip`.  Could you edit your post to include the results of `pip --version` and what OS you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `uninstall` subcommand was introduced in `pip` 0.6. Your version (0.3.1) does not include that feature.

Upgrade your pip:

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python
```

More information:

- http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html
- http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/news.html